# ways to open large-sized pdf without downloading (using open on javascript)

Tags: javascript, pdf, google-chrome-extension, data-uri

Good day,

I have a system that renders large amount of data through pdf ( 30mb + ). Now I want the user to view pdf first so he can either download it or just print it right away. as of the moment I am forcing the user to download the file since `open( 'datauri here' )` wont work with larger files.. the problem with downloading is that files are multiplying and consumes space over time and also its not necessary for me to download all files that that they want to print right away.
I need a functionality that is similar to chrome's preview when using `windows.print`

can you please suggest any ideas or other things to do this?

I am currently using [javascript library](http://pdfmake.org/#/) to create pdf (pdfmake). I am also using chrome as my main browser

Answer (score 1):

You would have to make sure that the PDF is optimized for fast web view, and that your server is using the byteserving protocol for serving the file.

If that is the case, a useful PDF viewer (such as the web browser component provided by Acrobat/Reader) understands this protocol and requests (after the first page plus overhead of the PDF) only the data for the pages which are to be displayed.

A quick search did, however, not reveal whether the Chrome PDF viewing component is smart enough to understand the byteserving protocol.

Comment: Thanks for the thought sir @max wyss.. temporarily im just setting the chrome browser to `open always` option so it would be automatically opened once download..  but its kinda dirty work-around.. my reports is optimized too I think.. i have a file of 15mb with 600+ pages on it pretty good rendered in < 1min... so my only problem really was the way the document is presented once the user click the print or generate report button.. anyways.. ill keep on searching for the right approach on this until I find one. :)